# If I say "I am a Portuguese translator"

Tags: meaning-in-context

...am I saying that I translate from Portuguese

or

that I am a translator from Portugal

or

anything else?

Comment: Could be either one. It depends on what you are really trying to say.

Comment: It could also mean you translate *into* Portuguese, or translate both ways, or that you're a translator of Portuguese descent.

Answer (score 2):

It is ambiguous.  If I say:

*"I am a Portuguese fisherman."*

There is no ambiguity.  Since you already recognize the possibility for misinterpreting the sentence, as a writer, you should add enough material to remove the ambiguity.